# Magento: Adding a 2nd Contact Form with a new form action

Tags: php, magento, contact-form

I am trying to add a new contact form in a CMS page that will send an email to a different email then the one I have set up in my existing contact form.

I have copied the form.pthml file in `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/contacts` and I have renamed it mycontactform.phtml

Then in a new CMS page in the contents section I call the file like this:

`{{block type='core/template' template='contacts/mycontactform.phtml'}}`

The content form works fine now when I visit the page on my website, but how do I get the form to send an email to a different email then my other form is sending to.

I think the form action is inside the phtml folder but I can't read PHP.

Comment: you have to create new controller and action to implement this

Comment: you need to change the form action with new action, and doing code for that as well.